# Delegate method seems to only be called when an associated method is called internally

Tags: objective-c, ios, delegates

Is there any structural reason why calling a method on a class instance would make the delegate methods associated with that method not fire?

*Class A:*

```
-(void)methodB //public
{
   NSURLConnection *url = [[NSURLConnection alloc]init];
   url.delegate = self;
   [url start];
}

- (void)connection: (NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse: (NSURLResponse *)response //delegate Method C
{
   NSLog (@"Connection worked");
}
```

Some method inside *Class X:*

```
ClassA *littleA = [[ClassA alloc] init];
[littleA methodB];
```

The problem is that `connection:didReceiveResponse:` isn't called.

However, if I do `[self methodB]` from inside the instance method of `ClassA` it apparently works.

Comment: This is a bit hard to follow without at least some dummy code. Are you re-implementing method `M`, or using the superclass's implementation? From where you you expect `D` to be called?

Comment: could you clarify the relation between `methodB` and `methodC` ?

Comment: I just risked the question, I was saying subclass when I meant instance of the class, sorry, Im still learning.

Comment: There's a _world_ of difference between subclassing and creating an instance. Can you please clean up the question so that it doesn't have two sections, one using "subclass" where you don't mean to? Also, you're still not explaining where `delegateMethodC` is supposed to be called.

Comment: I guess that's what I don't understand and am asking help with. When I don't create an instance of A (littleA) and call methodB from class A delegatemethodC fired every time like I want it to. Why isn't it firing when it's an instance?

Comment: What you just said doesn't make sense. If you're not creating an instance of A, how can you be calling a method on it? What are the contents of `methodB`? What's the _exact_ code you're using when `delegateMethodC` _does_ run?

Comment: If I run Class A by itself and somewhere in it say [self methodB] delegatemethodC will be called every time. But If I create an instance of Class A from Class X, when I call [littleA methodB] the delegatemethodC doesn't fire.

Comment: Eric, it is really hard to understand what you mean. How do you "associate" the delegate with the method? Definitely, paste more code or I doubt anybody will be able to help you.

Comment: Okay, that last comment is getting somewhere, but this is still too vague (ideally we shouldn't be having this kind of "chat" in comments). Could you just post the contents of `methodB`, please?

Comment: Just changed it with a theoretical example.

Comment: I've given a try to improve the question a little bit based on discussion in comments. Eric, is it what you meant?

Comment: Thanks @Krizz for the edit, the question is worded as I meant it.

Comment: Are you sure the the delegate method is not called? Because, I can see **no** reason why there should be any difference between calling `methodB` on instance and `self` which is actually an instance too - just the current instance.

Answer (score 1):

The NSURLConnection delegate method is not getting called because you have not set the delegate for said connection

```
NSURLConnection *url = [[NSURLConnection alloc]init];
url.delegate = self;
[url start];
```

Comment: That doesn't appear to affect the outcome. I've updated the question with that as well. Is there same way using self in the class that's instanced isn't translating to the class I'm calling it from?

Comment: I don't know if you missed it but you should also set the url for the NSURLConnection